# What is the largest possible Goomba Tower?

Tags: super-mario-odyssey

In *Super Mario Odyssey*, if Mario captures a Goomba then jumps on top of another Goomba, he can stack them to make a [Goomba Tower](https://www.mariowiki.com/Goomba_Tower). I’ve seen these stack as high as 10-15 Goombas, but I’m curious if it’s possible to go even bigger.

What is the largest possible Goomba Tower Mario can make? Is there a maximum size?

Comment: There probably isn't a hard cap. My guess is that you're only limited by the number of Goombas in the vicinity, which would make this more of a "where can I create the tallest Goomba tower" question. Fun question, I'm interested in the answer!

Comment: What is the purpose of the image? Or the wiki link?

Comment: Tallest I've found is 26 as seen in [this vid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_cf0lzjiZg).  I'm going to venture a guess and say that this is probably the tallest one you can make.

Comment: The boss probably stops spawning them because there would be too much entities to track.

Maybe with the one in Bowser's Keep you could spawn a few more?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [Mario Wiki](https://www.mariowiki.com/Goomba_Tower#Super_Mario_Odyssey), **the maximum number of Goombas in a tower in Super Mario Odessey is 30** according to this quote.

> The maximum number of Goombas there can be in a Goomba Tower is 30. This can be done in the [Darker Side](https://www.mariowiki.com/Darker_Side), in the area with the [Yoofoe](https://www.mariowiki.com/Yoofoe).

Answer (score 4):

A hard limit of **200 Goombas** has been found. The Switch will crash if any more Goombas are added. Note that this number cannot be achieved in game and a special way was used to create this tower. Legitimately, the limit of 30 in [redaddple8787's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/323082/25745) is the maximum possible without involving any cheat.